# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in jQuery load and iframe

Tags: javascript

when i use load html content of website using

$('.myClass').load('https://www.google.com');

or i use iframe and access data of google.com then it gives Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

Code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $('#root').load('http://www.google.com/');// Cross   origin Error

  $('#theFrame').contents() // Cross origin Error
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
 <title>Demo</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="static/javascript/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>

<iframe id="theFrame" src="http://www.google.com/" style="width:100%;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Error :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load google. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: If the server does not allow it, you can't access a website if you are not on the same origin. (You can't access foo.com if you are on bar.com) And for security purpose, you can't make your way around it (or *maybe* with another server that you own).

Answer (score 0):

You can do an end run around it with this proxy. https://cors.now.sh/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#root').load('https://cors.now.sh/http://www.google.com/');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```